# Numerically solve inseparable ODE in Python

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, python

I have an inseparable, first-order ODE of the form $$f'(t)=g(f'(t), f(t))$$
where $g$ is a rather monstrous combination of terms making it impossible to find some $h$ such that $f'(t)=h(f(t))$. I'd like to numerically integrate $f'(t)$ over time, ideally with something like scipy's `solve_ivp()`. However, I'm not sure how to best approach this problem as `solve_ivp()` (and the other ODE solvers I'm aware of) require the input function to have the form $f'(t)=h(f(t))$.

An option that comes to mind is to brute force $f(0)$ and $f(\Delta t)$ to estimate $f'(0)=\frac{f(\Delta t)-f(0)}{\Delta t}$. With $f'(0)$ estimated, I could then pass that into `solve_ivp()` and update this $f'(t)$-estimate each time `solve_ivp()` recalculates the derivative, passing the updated version to the subsequent call. I don't expect $f(t)$ to change rapidly with $t$, so using a "stale" value for $f'(t)$ is probably ok, but it feels like an awkward/wrong way of doing things.

Is there a simpler/better approach I've overlooked? Are there other Python packages better suited to this type of problem?

Comment: CouldI ask what $g$ is?

Comment: Sure! $g$ is a function that describes atmospheric CO2 on an Earth-like planet over time. The rate at which CO2 changes with time depends on the current amount of atmospheric CO2, and the temperature, T, of the planet. In turn, T depends on the CO2 concentration. So $g$ is a function of CO2 and and T, which is a parameterized fit based on CO2. The full parameterization is dozens of terms long.

Comment: Can one solve it for $f(t)$?

Comment: Yes, I can solve for $f(t)$ at a given time by providing initial guesses for CO2 and T, then iterating until convergence is reached.

Comment: Ok, I couldn’t offer you an easier method if you can’t solve for $f(t)$ analytically.